# Ending the program without the rest - need support

Tags: python

I have wrote this simple login and registartion program:

```
import os
from os import path


def start():
    startup = input ('are you an existing user? y/n : ')
    if startup == "y":
        print ("Lets login then")
        login()
    if startup == "n":
        print ("Lets make you an account")
        new_account()
    else:
        print ("That is an invalid input, please try again")
        start()


def new_account():

    new_username = input ('what do you want your username to be? ')
    print ('okay...')


    new_pass = input ('your new password... ')
    checker_pass = input ('retype it... ')

    if new_pass == checker_pass:
        print ('you have entered correct passwords')
        print ('Now please login ')
        print (' ')
        print ('..................................')
        print (' ')



    saveFile = open( new_username + '.txt','w')
    saveFile.write(new_pass)
    saveFile.close()

    login()


    else:
        print ('you have done something wrong. Please start again')
        new_account()



def login():

    print (' ')
    print ('..................................')
    print ("")

    user_name = input ('enter username: ')


    file_check = path.exists(user_name + '.txt')
    if file_check == False:
        print ("That username dosent exist, please start again")
        start()
    if file_check == True:
        Pass_check = open(user_name + '.txt' , 'r').read()


    password = input ('enter your password: ')

    if Pass_check != password:
        print('That didnt quite match. Please start again')
        start()


    elif Pass_check == password:
        print ('Welcome to your account.')

        start()
```

once i have entered a valid username or password it then says:
That is an invalid input, please try again
are you an existing user? y/n :

this is part of the program but isnt supposed to occur once you have been welcomed to your account.

has anyone got a soulution so that once you recieve "welcome to your account" nothing else happens.

i would like it done so that the program dosent fully stop as im looking to put this code into another program.

thanks fin.

THE OUTPUT:

```
are you an existing user? y/n : y
Lets login then

..................................

enter username: finndude
enter your password: test
Welcome to your account.
That is an invalid input, please try again
are you an existing user? y/n :
```

i dont want the last two lines to appear

Comment: Please indent well your code, it's not understandable for now

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. Also, some of your `if` statements should actually be `elif` (else-if) statements. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: cross-posted at [python-forum.io](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Need-Help-With-A-Problem-I-Have-Come-Across)

Comment: if you do not want the last two lines to appear then why are you callling ```start``` again after logging in . remove that call from ```login``` function and it should work perfectly

Comment: The `start` function logic should be, `if` `elif` `else` (one connected logic block), not `if` `if` `else` ( two separate logic blocks).

Answer (score -1):

Add a boolean flag value to the `start()` function that says whether to display the line or not. When calling from `login()` pass `True`, when calling recursively from `start()` then pass `False`.